# Android ndk-build: "error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_bad_alloc()"

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to compile my JNI layer for my native code. But ndk-build gives following error:

```
android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libtasr.a(rs_rescoreMngr.o): in function std::_Vector_base<NodeLabelAndTime_, std::allocator<NodeLabelAndTime_> >::_M_allocate(unsigned int) [clone .isra.258]:D:/Android/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/ext/new_allocator.h:90: error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
```

My Application.mk have following contents:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Most of the posts in this context suggest to use 'APP_STL := gnustl_static', as I have already done, but still error is not solved, please let me know if anyone have an answer/solution to this.

Thanks in advance